# How do these voltage vs. current graphs demonstrate how the resistance of each conductor changes during the experiment?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conductors

The method for the experiment was as follows:

> Connect the circuit shown above using the globe as a conductor and then replacing the globe with a 10Ω resistor. In each case record the voltmeter and ammeter readings in a suitable table for each setting on the power pack.

The graphs that following these instructions produced were:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

My question is, how do these graphs demonstrate how the resistance of each conductor changes during the experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hint, since this is a homework question. There are many types of resistors. One is the ohmic resistor (it corresponds to one of your graphs, I won't tell you which one) and it has constant resistance but most resistors have increasing resistance as temperature increases. That means the current decreases as temperature increases. (the temperature increase is due to higher values of current produced by higher voltages)

Comment: Having a bit of trouble working out what you mean. On my graphs, the current is increasing as the voltage does.

Comment: @MadBanners That's how the first graph looks, but the second graph looks like the last bits still increasing but at a lower rate i.e the gradient is lower.